# How are combination keypresses calculated in JavaScript CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, keypress, keycode

I've written a listener for key presses using CKEditor and jQuery

```
ckeditor.on('key', keyListener);

function keyListener(ev){
    console.log(ev.data.keyCode);
}
```

Now if I press `a` I get `65`, if I press `Ctrl` I get `1114129` and their combination yields `1114202`.

Can someone please explain the magic behind how this is calculated, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code it's calculated in the following way: 
ref: http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/event.html

```
/**
     * Gets a number represeting the combination of the keys pressed during the
     * event. It is the sum with the current key code and the {@link CKEDITOR#CTRL},
     * {@link CKEDITOR#SHIFT} and {@link CKEDITOR#ALT} constants.
     *
     *      alert( event.getKeystroke() == 65 );                                    // 'a' key
     *      alert( event.getKeystroke() == CKEDITOR.CTRL + 65 );                    // CTRL + 'a' key
     *      alert( event.getKeystroke() == CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 65 );   // CTRL + SHIFT + 'a' key
     *
     * @returns {Number} The number representing the keys combination.
     */
```